# Using php -l to verify syntax - behavior w/ opening tags

Tags: php, ruby, io, syntax-checking, phplint

I can't seem to find anything on this, and I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue or knows the reason why.

I have some PHP code that I'm trying to verify the syntax of before I save it into a database.

I'm in Ruby, but that doesn't matter. I'm using `php -l` to check the syntax and either clear it for saving or output any syntactical errors that occur.

This is a newer server install, so I'm guessing the issue is with something that needs installing or a setting in the `php.ini` that needs tweaking.

If the php content has a blatant error in it and starts with `<?`, the PHP lint function doesn't catch the error.

If the php content has the same blatant error and starts with `<?php`, the PHP link function catches the error.

The ruby code -- taking the content, putting it into a tempfile, then running php -l on the tempfile:

```
module PhpValidator
  def validate_php
    output = IO.popen("php -l", "r+") do |f|
      f.puts self.content
      f.close_write
      f.read
    end
    if $? != 0
      output.sub!("Errors parsing -", "")
      errors.add(:content, "contains invalid PHP: #{output}")
    end
  end
end
```

Then in the model where the content / php is being saved:

```
before_save :validate_php
```

Example PHP that returns invalid with

```
<?
echo "test";
dsfaks;fjaskl;fkas0f9qiroawlsfkasdfa;'
?>
```

Comment: The crude workaround would be piping it through `php -l -dshort_open_tag=on` to force `<?` tokens to be recognized.

Comment: I was looking at the wrong `php.ini` file on the server. Looks like short_open_tag is turned off, which we don't want anyway. Changing that and turning on display_errors....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple issue. I was looking at the wrong `php.ini` file.

From the command line, I did:

`php -i | grep php.ini` to figure out which php.ini file was active.

Then, looking in there, I noticed that:

`short_open_tag` the preference was set to `Off` and it needs to be `On`.

Secondly, I was getting a simple `Errors parsing -` response when there was a syntax error, which meant I also needed to turn on `display_errors` in the php.ini file.

Simple issue, took me 5 minutes after I thought it through, but I'll leave this here for the next person.

Comment: `php -d short_open_tag=On -l ...` does the trick, too.